# Storing arbitrary data in an $.event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 64 } );
```

There is data being attached to the event in the second parameter. Now I have seem that kind of syntax in a lot of plugins and was wondering, what's the use of attaching arbitrary data to a $.event/custom event?

I have seen the jQuery docs [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and also [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

I am wondering, if the only usage of attaching data to a event is as follows:

```
                   var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 64 } );
                   // above is the line I am having difficulty understanding
                   // the usage of arbitrary data with the $.event is quite 
                   // elusive to a novice developer like me                
                    $(window).on('keydown' , function(e){
                            console.log('key 64 pressed');
                        });

                    press =  function(){
                        $(window).trigger(e);
                    }

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        press();
                    }, 2000);
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tqco7u6j/1/)

I.e. triggering an event on a specific key or a specific element, I mean is this the only use of attaching arbitrary data to an `$.event`?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you are using your code that behaves in some way depending on the interaction.

In your example, you are "manually" triggering the `keydown` event on that input in order to "trigger" the `event-listeners` listening to this event.

Probably on this example you have a idle logout system going on and you activated something to keep the session alive on your `UI` as long as needed.

The other day I had to use something similar in order to keep a dropdown open in a third party plugin that was closing a drop down on selection after a search.